# Reducing the amount of words in a string

Tags: python

Im using a simple function that should filter all words with a length < 3. Therefore I have written the following function.

```
def my_tokenizer(tokens):
 tokens = [t for t in tokens if len(t) > 3]
 return tokens

x = my_tokenizer("sdfgds hj")
print x
```

X however gives my an empty array. Any thoughts on where I go wrong?

Comment: `[t for t in tokens.split(' ') if len(t) > 3]`? Otherwise you are looping through the string character by character.

Comment: An alternative method is to use a `filter` function (which I only suggest because you specifically use the word "filter" in your question), e.g. `return list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 3, tokens.split()))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You treat "tokens", a string, as a sequence, so it is going to loop through each character.  The string method [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) will separate the string on whitespace characters, (words).  So try:

```
tokens = [t for t in tokens.split() if len(t) > 3]
```